# Finding The Slope of a Line Intersecting a Region $R$ Bounded by a Curve $f(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant enclosed by $f(x) = x - x^2$ and the $x$-axis. A line, passing through the origin, runs through region $R$ and cuts it so that the area of the lower portion of $R$ is seven times the area of the upper portion of $R$. Find the slope of the line.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I set up a few integrals, using "m" as the slope, and saying that the area below the line is 7 times the area between the curve and the line. But it didn't make a lot of sense, as I technically didn't know which limits to use, not knowing where the two functions intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** Draw a picture.

It is easy to compute the total area $A$.

Draw a line of slope $m$ through the origin, where $m$ feels roughly right. The line meets the curve at $x=0$ and $x=1-m$.

The area of the upper part is
$$\int_0^{1-m} \left((x-x^2)-mx\right)\,dx.$$
Set this equal to $\frac{7}{8}A$.